# Get The Full List Of Objects In A Dictionary Values

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have this dictonary:

```
private Dictionary<int, ICar> _ICarsDic;
```

The object ICar actually contains another list of objects:

```
public interface ICar 
{
    int carId { get; set; }
    string carName { get; set; }
    List<IBrandsDetails> brandsDetails { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to write a function that returns me in a single list all the brandsDetails in all my `_ICarsDic` values.

I am sure LINQ does that (don't want to write an ugly loop) but I'm new to this so would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Eneumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

```
List<IBrandsDetails> list =  _ICarsDic.SelectMany(r => r.Value.brandsDetails)
                                      .ToList();
```

Comment: I guess it should be `List<List<IBrandsDetails>>`

Comment: @yogi, no it will return List<IBrandsDetails>,

Comment: @yogi That exactly illustrates the difference between `Select(...)` and `SelectMany(...)`. With just `Select` you *would* get an `IEnumerable<List<IBrandsDetails>>` which would become `List<List<IBrandsDetails>>` by `ToList`. But with `SelectMany` all the sequences are concatenated into one (non-nested) sequence.

Comment: Wow, you're fast! Seems I was really close, but mist the ToList() part :-)  Thank you!

Comment: Let's say that the IBrandDetails is now a Dictionnary where I still need to get it's values. How would you do the same?  Dictionnary<int,IBrandsDetails> brandsDetails { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

```
var brandDetails = _ICarsDic.Values.SelectMany(c => c.brandsDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the linq as

```
var listOfObjects = _ICarsDic.SelectMany(t => t.Value.brandsDetails).ToList();
```